# Quarkus: Testing native image built in container

Tags: docker, gradle, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

The [Quarkus - Building a Native Executable](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) guide discusses how to build and test a native executable, and also how to build a native executable inside a docker container.

I've followed this guide to set up a common native executable build using Docker, that we are using on our CI server and also to build it locally regardless of host operating system.

However, the produced native executable must be run on the architecture used by the builder docker image, but the Maven and Gradle test tasks try to execute the produced image directly. For example, the docker build produces a Linux native-image, but we want to run the tests from OSX and Windows systems too.

How can I tell Quarkus to run the native tests against the built docker container, instead of the raw binary?

Comment: You may want to upvote this request for enhancement: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[QuarkusIntegrationTest](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-integration-test) is what you are looking for

**ORIGINAL**
We don't have such a capability yet. Please submit your idea at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/quarkus-dev/IdwKtwdm7DY/eJKrHfX3AwAJ